# Set stabilizer of subset vs. set stabilizer of inverse subset

Tags: finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite group and $A\subseteq G$ a subset. The left regular action of $G$ on itself induces a natural action on the powerset of $G$:
$$G\times 2^G\rightarrow 2^G,(g,A)\longmapsto gA:=\{ga|a\in A\}.
$$
The *set stabilizer* of $A$ in $G$ is defined via:
$$G_A:=\{g\in G|gA=A\}.
$$Note that $gA=A$ only has to hold setwise, not pointwise. (Thus, $G_A\neq\cap_{a\in A}G_a$.)
Let us write $A^{-1}:=\{a^{-1}|a\in A\}$ and $|\cdot|$ for the number of elements. I conjecture, that in general

> $$|G_A|\neq|G_{A^{-1}}|.
> $$

Do you know a (nice, maybe smallest) example for a finite group $G$ and a subset $A$ such that $|G_A|\neq|G_{A^{-1}}|$ (or equivalently: *The $G$-orbits of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have different sizes.*)? Certainly, $G$ will have to be non-abelian. A̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶$̶|̶G̶|̶>̶2̶6̶$̶,̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶c̶a̶l̶c̶u̶l̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶G̶A̶P̶ ̶d̶e̶m̶o̶n̶s̶t̶r̶a̶t̶e̶.̶

**Or:** (if I'm mistaken) Can you prove that indeed $|G_A|=|G_{A^{-1}}|$?

Thank you.

Comment: This is equivalent to: size of the orbit of $A$ by the left action is equal to the orbit of $A$ for the right action. Should be true.

Comment: The user ahulpke posted an answer which helped me solve my question. Somehow, this answer has vanished. (Something seems to be wrong with the stackexchange system...) Like I conjectured $|G_A|≠|G_{A^{−1}}|$ in general. A smallest example is: $G:=A_4$, $A:=\{(),(1,2)(3,4),(1,2,3),(1,3,4)\}$. In this case $G_A$ and $G_{A^{−1}}$ have different sizes. (@baharampuri: This also shows, that the equivalence of left and right action doesn't go too far, in particular orbit sizes may differ.) My mistake was that I was misusing GAP to check the claim. Credit goes to ahulpke for anticipating this misuse.

Comment: Two answers were posted yesterday by two different users. Both elected to delete their answer by choice. No issue with the system. Might as well post an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encouraged by anon, I am repeating the counter example from my comment as a proper answer to my own question:

An example showing that $|G_A|\neq|G_{A^{-1}}|$ is:
$$
G:=A_4,A:=\{(),(1,2)(3,4),(1,2,3),(1,3,4)\}.
$$(The set stabilizers of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have sizes 1 and 2.) baharampuri has correctly pointed out a connection to the right action. The example demonstrates that for the action on $2^G$ stabilizer sizes (and thus orbit sizes) of one "point" $A\in 2^G$ may differ for left and right action.